# handmade Makefile to Cmake with static library

Tags: cmake

Here is a MakeFile for my project, since I'm using CLion for as my IDE, I need a Cmake configuration. I could not convert the following Makefile correctly.

```
all: VisualCryptography

VisualCryptography: VisualCryptographyGPU.o VisualCryptographyMC.o ExtVisualCryptographyCPU.o ExtVisualCryptographyGPU.o ExtVisualCryptographyMC.o VisualCryptographyCPUTest.o

g++ *.o  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -lpthread ./lib/libVC.a -o VisualCryptography
rm -rf *.o

VisualCryptographyMC.o: ./source/VisualCryptographyMC.c
g++ -lpthread -c ./source/VisualCryptographyMC.c

VisualCryptographyCPUTest.o: ./source/VisualCryptographyCPUTest.c
g++ -lpthread -c ./source/VisualCryptographyCPUTest.c

VisualCryptographyGPU.o: ./source/VisualCryptographyGPU.cu
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -c -arch=compute_20 -code=sm_20 -lm ./source/VisualCryptographyGPU.cu

ExtVisualCryptographyCPU.o: ./source/ExtVisualCryptographyCPU.c
g++ -c ./source/ExtVisualCryptographyCPU.c

ExtVisualCryptographyGPU.o: ./source/ExtVisualCryptographyGPU.cu
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -c -arch=compute_20 -code=sm_20 -lm ./source/ExtVisualCryptographyGPU.cu

ExtVisualCryptographyMC.o: ./source/ExtVisualCryptographyMC.c
g++ -lpthread -c ./source/ExtVisualCryptographyMC.c

clean:
rm -rf *.o VisualCryptography
```

Here is my CMakeList.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(VC)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package (Threads)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
link_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(SOURCE_FILES
    source/common.h
    source/ExtVisualCryptographyGPU.cu
    source/ExtVisualCryptographyCPU.c
    source/ExtVisualCryptographyMC.c
    source/preprocess.h
    source/VisualCryptographyCPUDefault.h
    source/VisualCryptographyCPUTest.c
    source/VisualCryptographyCPUTest.h
    source/VisualCryptographyMC.c
    source/VisualCryptographyGPU.cu
    source/VisualCryptographyGPU.h
    source/VisualCryptographyMC.h)
add_executable(VC ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(VC ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} libVC.a)
```

Where am I doing wrong?

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lVC
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/VC.dir/build.make:172: recipe for target 'VC' failed
make[3]: *** [VC] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/VC.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/VC.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/VC.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/VC.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'VC' failed
make: *** [VC] Error 2
```

I also should note that the libVC.a is in lib sub dir of my project, and all other source codes are in source sub dir. the main function is also in libVC.a, which is static.

Comment: Have you tried with a full path like `target_link_libraries(VC ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libVC.a)`? But I would recommend to use an [import library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html?highlight=import%20library#imported-libraries) instead.

Comment: I think that it is not such a good idea that your executable (`VC`) has the same name as the lib that you are linking against (`libVC.a`). Have you tried changing your project name and executable name to something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the name as oLen suggested, this behavior is seen in some versions of Cmake. You can check another version if you insist on using the same name.